# python threads for audio playing different sounds, do not seem to be locking correctly, and beginning of function returned to after thread calls

Tags: python, multithreading, locks

I am working on code that plays out sounds from the computer based on input from a keyboard.  The sounds stored as wav files and played out with PyAudio.  The latency between sounds being played out for two successive keyboard strokes was too slow, however, so I am trying to add in threads to speed the I/O time up.  However, the audio now comes out scratchy and I don't think the locks on the threads are working.  Here is the relevant code:

```
while threading.activeCount() < NUM_THREADS:
   message, delta_time = midi_in.get_message()
   if message:
    if message[2] == 0:
     continue
    elif message and (str(message[1]) == "108" or str(message[1]) == "107"):
     break
    else:
     t = threading.Thread(target=play, args=(message,))
     lock = threading.Lock()

     lock.acquire()
     t.start()
     lock.release()



def play(message):

  WAVE_FILENAME = "final"+str(message[1]) + '.wav'
  CHUNK = 1024
  wf = wave.open(WAVE_FILENAME)
  p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

  stream = p.open(format=p.get_format_from_width(wf.getsampwidth()),
                 channels = wf.getnchannels(),
             rate = wf.getframerate(),
                 output = True)
  data = wf.readframes(CHUNK)
  while data != '':
   stream.write(data)
   data = wf.readframes(CHUNK)

  stream.stop_stream()
  stream.close()

  p.terminate()
```

Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: As a side note, your spacing makes your code very hard to read. The standard is 4 spaces for an indent; 2 spaces is still readable; an arbitrary mix of 1 space, 3 spaces, and tabs is just a mess.

Answer (score 2):

> I don't think the locks on the threads are working

The reason is that the following creates a new lock:

```
lock = threading.Lock()
```

In other words, you are not using the same lock across the iterations of the loop; each iteration has its own lock. As a result, no synchronization takes place.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you have to pass in the lock to you're worker threads, like so:

```
def play(message, lock):
    lock.acquire()
    # do something with a restricted ressource 
    lock.release()
```

Then start a thread and pass in the lock:

```
t = threading.Thread(target=play, args=(message, lock))
```

Answer (score 0):

There are (at least) two problems here.

First, as NPE explains, you're creating a different lock for each thread. Acquiring a lock only synchronizes you with other threads acquiring *the same* lock, not *any* lock.

Second, as Theodros Zelleke explains, you're not actually acquiring the lock in the worker threads; you're only locking the main thread, while it's creating threads. This won't do any good.

If you want to make sure that only one thread can work at a time, you need to do this:

```
lock = threading.Lock()
while threading.activeCount() < NUM_THREADS:
    message, delta_time = midi_in.get_message()
    if message:
        if message[2] == 0:
            continue
        elif message and (str(message[1]) == "108" or str(message[1]) == "107"):
            break
    else:
        t = threading.Thread(target=play, args=(message, lock))
        t.start()

def play(message, lock):
    WAVE_FILENAME = "final"+str(message[1]) + '.wav'
    CHUNK = 1024
    wf = wave.open(WAVE_FILENAME)
    p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

    with lock:
        stream = p.open(format=p.get_format_from_width(wf.getsampwidth()),
                        channels = wf.getnchannels(),
                        rate = wf.getframerate(),
                        output = True)
        data = wf.readframes(CHUNK)
        while data != '':
            stream.write(data)
            data = wf.readframes(CHUNK)

        stream.stop_stream()
        stream.close()
```

Note that I used `with lock:` instead of explicit `lock.acquire()` and `lock.release()`. This is more than just convenience—if anything you do under the lock can throw an exception, `lock.release()` will never get called, unless you either use a `with` statement or a `try`.

If you want to block the main thread, as well as all `play` threads, you could restore your existing lock code (or, better, change it to a `with lock:` block), but be sure you're putting the locking where you actually want it.

Meanwhile: You realize that if you get this right, you'll be implementing a monophonic synth with an infinite backlog, so no sound can play until the previous sounds have all finished? That's an add way to fix latency problems…

A few more comments while I'm at it:

- Why are you doing `if message and …` inside `if message:`?
- Why are you doing `str(message[1]) == "108"` instead of just `message[1] == 108`?

Comment: thank you for the help and code suggestions.  The reason I was putting the locking so that no sound could play until all previous sounds finished was to make sure the playing of each audio clip didn't disrupt the other ones.  It seems like if there is overlap between the sounds playing out - the sound becomes fuzzy/crackly and the quality is not very good.  I figured this was an issue with competing for I/O resources on the computer.  Is there a good way around this that you know of?

Comment: Actually - I just got the audio working more cleanly using pygame's mixer

Comment: @user1201163: Yeah, using a mixer is probably the right solution to your higher-level problem here. We should have all addressed that, instead of just trying to explain what you were doing wrong with your locks.